# Remove resize border and drawn in the occupied area?

Tags: c++, winapi

When I remove the sizing border of a window, it leaves black areas around it.

Is it possible to somehow tell the window to occupy/paint these areas, as there's no sizing border anymore?

A reproducible example: launch a instance of `chrome` browser with:
`chrome.exe -app=https://www.google.com`

Remove the sizing border:

```
LONG lStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
lStyle &= ~(WS_THICKFRAME | WS_DLGFRAME);
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle);
```

> WS_THICKFRAME
> 0x00040000L
> The window has a sizing border. Same as the WS_SIZEBOX style.
>
> WS_DLGFRAME
> 0x00400000L
> The window has a border of a style typically used with dialog boxes. A window with this style cannot have a title bar.

The black areas im talking about:  left, right, bottom.

[image]

As suggested, I use `SetWindowPos()` with `SWP_FRAMECHANGED`, but it didn't result in any visible change.

```
int flags = SWP_NOSENDCHANGING | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_FRAMECHANGED;
SetWindowPos(hWnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, flags);
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{   
    HWND hwnd = FindWindowW( L"Chrome_WidgetWin_1", nullptr );
    //HWND hwnd = FindWindowW( L"Notepad", nullptr );

    std::cout << "hwnd: " << hwnd << "\n";

    LONG lStyle = GetWindowLong( hwnd, GWL_STYLE );
    lStyle &= ~( WS_THICKFRAME | WS_DLGFRAME );
    SetWindowLong( hwnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle );

    int flags = SWP_NOSENDCHANGING | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_FRAMECHANGED;
    auto swp = SetWindowPos( hwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, flags );

    std::cout << "swp: " << swp << "\n";
}
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau you closed my question? that question the user is adding/changing  a border edge i'm removing...
btw, I  tried sending with `SetWindowPos` `SWP_FRAMECHANGED`, but it still black, the areas are not being painted.

Comment: The solution applies to any kind of change to the NC area. Can you show your call to `SetWindowPos`? Make sure to combine `SWP_FRAMECHANGED` with `SWP_NO*` flags for each parameter you don't supply.

Comment: @zett42 `auto flags = SWP_NOSENDCHANGING | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_FRAMECHANGED;
 SetWindowPos(hWnd,0,0,0,0,0, flags);`

Comment: You are missing `SWP_NOMOVE` and `SWP_NOSIZE`.

Comment: @zett42 I had the flags you mentioned in another if block, even with them got the same result, i added a mode to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Considering that it works for notepad, it must be a specialty of Google Chrome. The difference should be that Chrome is drawing into the non-client area of the window (i.e. the tabs appear in the title bar, which is kind of special). That means that Chrome is doing a lot of drawing and computations by itself. Apparently, the code does not handle the case that the window has no sizing borders (because Chrome by itself does not support this). Instead, they hardcoded that the client rectangle is always smaller by the sizing border width, even if there is no sizing border.

A workaround would be to start Chrome with `--disable-dwm-composition`. But I do not really know if there are any unintended side effects when using this option.

### Details

Digging through the [source code of Chromium](https://source.chromium.org/), one can see:

- First note that the WinAPI function `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea()` [is called](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:ui/views/win/hwnd_message_handler.cc;l=3484;drc=71ff7fa8c189cc0991f6a473e8b496843b27c116?ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc), which means that Chromium has indeed [the special drawing logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to draw the window frame by itself.
- To remove the standard frame, the [`WM_NCCALCSIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-nccalcsize) message [is handled](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:ui/views/win/hwnd_message_handler.cc;l=2254?ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc). Therein, we can find a [call to `GetClientAreaInsets()`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:ui/views/win/hwnd_message_handler.cc;l=2296?ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc), which returns the "insets", i.e. 4 values (for left, top, bottom and right) by which the client rectangle becomes smaller.
- Searching for `GetClientAreaInsets()`, we see that its implementations essentially [calls `ui::GetFrameThickness()`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/ui/views/frame/browser_desktop_window_tree_host_win.cc;l=318?ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc&start=1) and uses its return value as the inset value. But only if the window is not in fullscreen; indeed, the black border effect does not appear in fullscreen.
- [`ui::GetFrameThickness()`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:ui/base/win/hwnd_metrics.cc;l=14?ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc) calls ([indirectly](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:ui/display/win/screen_win.cc;l=628?ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc)) the WinAPI function [`GetSystemMetricsForDpi()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetricsfordpi) to get the values of [`SM_CXSIZEFRAME` and `SM_CXPADDEDBORDER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics), i.e. the size of the sizing border. Their sum is returned.
- The `SM_CXSIZEFRAME` and `SM_CXPADDEDBORDER` apparently map to the registry values `BorderWidth` and `PaddedBorderWidth` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics`. I.e. they are system settings. Changing these values (to a notable more negative value) and restarting the PC does not make the drawn border of windows larger on Windows 10 (although it did in earlier Windows versions). But they do change the invisible "capture" area of the sizing borders. And, in our case here, the black borders shown by Chrome also become larger.
- I think the former sizing border areas are drawn black after removing them because of the `BLACK_BRUSH` in [`HWNDMessageHandler::OnPaint`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:ui/views/win/hwnd_message_handler.cc;l=2506?ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc).

So, in a nutshell, Chrome is simply making the client area smaller by the sizing borders, regardless if the sizing borders actually exist or not. And then draws everything in there. If Chrome were supporting removed sizing borders officially, it could be considered as a bug. But I don't think they do.

How do we work around this behavior from the "outside"?

- Considering that `SM_CXSIZEFRAME` and `SM_CXPADDEDBORDER` are global settings, changing them (by means of the registry or the [`SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETBORDER,...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa) function is probably out of the question for practical uses.
- But looking through the source code, we note that in [`HWNDMessageHandler::UpdateDwmFrame()`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:ui/views/win/hwnd_message_handler.cc;l=3476?ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc) the function [`ui::win::IsAeroGlassEnabled()`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:ui/base/win/shell.cc;l=182?ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc) is called, which in turn returns false if the [`disable-dwm-composition`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:ui/base/ui_base_switches.cc;l=38?ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc) commandline flag is specified. Hence, starting Chrome with the `--disable-dwm-composition` flag and then running the code in the OP (removing `WS_THICKFRAME | WS_DLGFRAME`) does the trick for me. The invisible sizing borders are truly gone, i.e. clicks onto the space where they were are no longer registered by Chrome but by the window below it (e.g. the Desktop).
  [image]

Comment: You launched chrome with `chrome.exe -app=https://www.google.com --disable-dwm-composition`? here it continued with the same black areas around it.

Comment: @touraille Yes, if I execute `chrome.exe -app=https://www.google.com --disable-dwm-composition` from cmd or powershell, and then run your code from the original post, there are no black bars anymore. There were no other chrome processes running while doing this. Without the `--disable-dwm-composition`, I do get black bars. I have Chrome 102 installed, Windows 10 21H2, standard Windows design.

Comment: This is how it looks here launching as `chrome.exe -app=https://www.google.com --disable-dwm-composition` and running the code,  https://i.imgur.com/x1jo5XX.png

Comment: @touraille I added an image to my answer how it looks for me. Note the minimize, maximize and close buttons: I get the normal "flat" ones like in your image when I start without `--disable-dwm-composition`, but with the flag I get the ones where each button has a dark border. I do get the normal ones even with `--disable-dwm-composition` if I start a chrome process the normal way, first. So I suspect you had an existing chrome process running? If yes, try to close all chrome windows/procs first and see if that helps. If yes, forcing a new process [is possible](https://superuser.com/a/1281222).

Comment: Also, looking through the code, you could also try the flag `--disable-windows10-custom-titlebar` or setting the Windows compatibility mode to Windows 7. But in my cases, both resulted in undesired graphic glitches. I should maybe also stress again that all of these are workarounds or hacks that cause chrome to take different code paths where `ui::GetFrameThickness()` happens to be not taken. The devs simply did not anticipate that someones removes the sizing borders.

Comment: You are on w11 right? im on win10, maybe is this. Do you know a way to also get ride of the chrome titlebar? similar to the --kiosk method, the problem of --kiosk is it launch the chrome with fullscreen

Comment: @touraille I am on Windows 10. Have you tried closing all chrome processes first before running with `--disable-windows10-custom-titlebar` and hiding the sizing borders? Also, sorry, no idea if hiding the titlebar is possible.